# XSD parsing documents and elements

Tags: python, xml-parsing, xsd, pyxb

I have a `xsd` for which I used `pyxb` to generate object classes for. So far everything is working, i'm able to take in documents, error handling, etc. is working fine. My only question is this, I have the following in my xsd:

```
<xs:element name="users">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="user" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I have the `user` complex type defined elsewhere. Sometimes I want to take a `user` from the main xml document and I want to create python class bindings from it...but i'm not able to. `pyxb` only allows me to create from an entire document(using the `CreateFromDocument` function). Is there anyway to get just that one `user` element?

I read the following:

https://developer.yahoo.com/python/python-xml.html

http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/api/pyxb.binding.basis.element-class.html

http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/userref_pyxbgen.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CreateFromDocument() will create a binding for any XML fragment that is a top-level element in the schema.  So you should have been able to do:

```
instance = user_xsd.CreateFromDocument(string)
```

without going through a dom instance first.  There are a lot of examples that do exactly this in the tests directory.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was hidden will into the docs.

http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/PyXB-1.2.2/examples.html

say you have one `user` xml document. You can do:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
dom = minidom.parseString(string)

# import the xml file you get from pyxbgen
import user_xsd
user_xsd.CreateFromDOM(dom.documentElement)
```